# You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 8

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle

Please wait before marking the question duplicate. I already have seen all related question. but I can't figure out the problem. this is old version:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 26
versionCode 8
versionName "1.5"
```

and this is new version code:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 26
versionCode 20
versionName "2.0"
```

I am using android studio version 3.0 beta 6
and to solve the problem what I have done already.
1. Invalidate Cache/Restart
2. Clean Build and Rebuild Project
3. Tried with different apk version code and version name
4. Disable instant run

and here is app's manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
```

Comment: do you have <uses-sdk ... /> in your manifest file?

Comment: no here is my manifest file,

Comment: have you already uploaded an APK file of version 8 to Google Play Store?

Comment: yes, the current version is 8. but I am trying to update my app

Comment: bump up your version code to 9 and your version name to "1.6", re-run the app and then try to upload to Google Play again.

Comment: I already have tried with version code 9 but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

About an hour later I am able to solve my problem. I have just signed my APK with android studio 2.3.3(latest stable version). And it worked.